# Working with batch programming

Tags: batch-file, lua

I have LUBs files (LUA compiled files) and I want them decompiled.
I use luadec.exe to decompile them.

However, I have a lot of LUBs and I decompiling each one of them takes a really good amount of time, so I thought of using a batch procedure program to this for me. It would have to:

- Open a specific path where the LUBs and the subfolders with LUBs are;
- Make a list with all the LUBs it find;
- For each file, run the specific command: `luadec.exe %s -o %s.lua`;
- (Optional) Delete the LUBs

I don't know if it is better to do this using a C program or using the batch file. Anyways, I thought asking for help here was a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: To your question : its better to do it with batch.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /r C:\folderwithlubs %%a in (*.lub) do luadec.exe %%a -o %%a.lua
```

You could even run that in a cmd prompt as it's just one line, if you do just remember to remove one of the `%`'s.

```
for /r C:\folderwithlubs %a in (*.lub) do luadec.exe %a -o %a.lua
```

In your example you specify `%s` as parameters, I have presumed this is a variable for the file it's is currently executing on, if it really is a literal command just let me know and I will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a very easy process to do using a BATCH file written in Notepad/Notepad++. A quick Google search for "opening a path", "listing files from a directory", "running a command on files" and "deleting files" with regards to using a BATCH file should make this an easy task.

From when I used to do a lot of BATCH programming I remember using this site: http://ss64.com/nt/